# jQuery OR Selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, if-statement

Just trying to figure out how you can test multiple selectors within an existing piece of code i.e. like this

```
if (!(jQuery('#selector1 || #selector2').hasClass('some-class'))) {
//code here
}
```

This doesn't work but wondering if there is anything I can do to make it work ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just select them both, if either of them has the class `some-class`, the condition is true:

```
if (!jQuery('#selector1, #selector2').hasClass('some-class')) {
    //code here
}
```

Or, if I misinterpreted your logic, you can (and should, for sake of speed and simplicity) break those into two:

```
if (!(jQuery('#selector1').hasClass('some-class') || jQuery('#selector2').hasClass('some-class'))) {
    //code here
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot - yeah the second bit of code you added is what i am after. thanks

Comment: @hunter - your answer is incorrect, you're checking for the class on a descendant (and it's much less efficient).

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple, it's a comma ;)

```
if (!(jQuery('#selector1 .some-class, #selector2 .some-class'))) {
//code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not that I know of. maybe just do something like this:

```
if((!$('#selectorid1').hasClass(class)) || (!$('#selectorid2').hasClass(class))){}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((!('#selector1').hasClass('some-class')) || (!('#selector2').hasClass('some-class'))) { 
//code here 
}
```

Why not like this?